# Does node.js --max-old-space-size include forked processes?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, v8

I'm working on resolving out-of-memory errors in a node.js application and using the `--max-old-space-size` parameter when launching `node` to set the size to 4096MB, the maximum accoring to https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/FAQ (I can't find simular documentation for the current version of node.js).

What I'm wondering is if that 4096MB limit is imposed on everything used by that single node.js script, or if each process is allocated 4096MB?

In other words, if I `fork()` additional processes from inside the script, does each forked process get 4096MB to work with, or do they all draw from the same 4096MB pool?

Comment: `systemctl status` seems to indicate each process gets it's own allocation (tried to paste the example but can't format it here).  That said I'd still like some "official" confirmation.

Answer (score 16):

My team had the same question and so we tested this on our staging server. We use the native node `cluster` module with `forever` as a daemon.

For every forked process, appearing in `htop`, we can see the `--max-old-space-size` flag being passed along. Each each child process had the flag, including processes forked later on in the app.

We did NOT need to manually pass the flag through `cluster` module itself.

> In other words, if I fork() additional processes from inside the script, does each forked process get 4096MB to work with, or do they all draw from the same 4096MB pool?

I believe this is the case with the tests that we ran at the time.

[image]

Comment: "I believe this is the case with the tests that we ran at the time" is an affirmative answer to an either-or question.